# Adding items to listview after it has been populated using cursor

Tags: android, listview

On my (first) android app, I have a diary screen that shows a list of appointments the user has. Currently the app shows a list of appointments with the core information displayed on the list (start time, end time, etc).

In order for the user to see when they have free time between appointments, they need to painstakingly look at all the times and work out when there is a gap. I would like to create this gap visually to make it more intuitive for the user.

Currently I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to fill the listview from an SQLite table, but to my knowledge, I cannot edit the results of a cursor (as - it is my understanding - that the cursor is only a pointer to the database, not a copy of the information).

Ideally what I would like to do is detect whenever there is a gap between appointments and insert an extra row where there is a gap (regardless of the size of the gap - just a single row). I would like this 'gap' row to state how many minutes of free time the gap contains.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

I have added my ideal layout below:

[image]

Comment: You can see answer on similar question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197274/how-to-add-multiple-header-views-in-a-listview)

Comment: I can't really see how that answer is appropriate - could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

You could make an appointment class:

```
class Appointment implements Comparable<Appointment> {

    // your appointment class

    private String title;
    private Date time;
    private boolean isFreeTime;
    etc.

    Constructor
    Setters/Getters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Appointment appointment) {
        return 0; //Here you sort by date or whatever you want
    }
}
```

Go through the cursor before setting the adapter.

```
ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

if (cursor == null)
    return;

cursor.moveToFirst();

while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(/*your stuff*/);
    appointments.add(appointment);

    cursor.moveToNext();

}

cursor.close();
```

Then go though the list and add all your free time rows.

```
appointments.setFreeTime(true);
```

Use

```
Collections.sort(appointments);
```

Extend BaseAdapter and pass the ArrayList to that adapter

This should work :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I actually already had an Appointment class created so that's fine. So essentially what you're saying is that the cursor should populate an ArrayList of appointment objects, which I then insert various 'free-time' appointments into at the appropriate locations, then use the array list to populate the listview? Thank you so much for explaining it to me - if I'm wrong about anything then please let me know! I will attempt this now :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Hope it's working for you. :)